# Pure JavaScript replacement for Lodash'es `omit()`

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have been looking for a replacement for Lodash `omit()` using only JavaScript. This is what I want to achieve:

```
function omit(obj, attr) {
  // @obj: original object
  // @attr: string, attribute I want to omit
  // return a new object, do not modify the original object
}
```

So far, I have found this solution:

```
let { attr, ...newObj } = obj;
```

But it only works if `attr` is known. I want `attr` to be dynamic, so `attr` should be a string. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) function supports excluding multiple keys. The function accepts a list of parameters, an array of keys, or a combination of a parameters and arrays. To preserve that functionality, you can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) them to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), convert the object to an array of entries via [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), filter it, and then convert back to an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
function omit(obj, ...keys) {
  const keysToRemove = new Set(keys.flat()); // flatten the props, and convert to a Set
  
  return Object.fromEntries( // convert the entries back to object
    Object.entries(obj) // convert the object to entries
      .filter(([k]) => !keysToRemove.has(k)) // remove entries with keys that exist in the Set
  );
}

console.log(omit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }, 'bar'));
console.log(omit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }, 'bar', 'baz'));
console.log(omit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }, ['bar', 'baz']));
console.log(omit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }, 'bar', ['baz']));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a computed property name to "extract" the property you want to remove while destructuring:

```js
function omit(obj, attr) {
  const { [attr]: _, ...newObj } = obj;
  return newObj;
}

console.log(omit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }, 'bar'));
```

Comment: Precisely correct.  It might be worth noting that lodash _is_ pure JavaScript just to correct the OP's misconception.

Comment: lodash omit's second parameter is an array.